# why can't processes communication with each other directly?

Tags: linux, process, operating-system

I mean don't use ipc methods such as pipe ,shared memory.Process A access Process B directly.

Comment: And how would they communicate "directly" ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If any process will be able to communicate with anyone other then there would be no data protection at all. Communications can be seen as reading from other process memory, if you don't provide mechanisms for doing this the only way they can communicate is by reading each other's memory and writing there too. If this happens someone may create a program which will read all sensitive information from other programs.

Long story short, this is impossible for security reasons.

Comment: yeah,thanks.communicate through kernel can be safety,is that right?the design intent?

Comment: Almost yes, through kernel one can implement some safety precautions